# Pairwise comparison algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I am interested in performing **pairwise comparisons** -calculating the **euclidean distance** between each pair and find the pairs with the highest distance- efficiently. The pairs to be compared should *not include neither comparisons with themselves nor with of repeated pairs* (i.e. commutative property holds). I could not find any useful resources/algorithms regarding this (trivial?) case.

Here is a short example of what I looking for:

Say I have 4 elements (each is a tuple of 5 values)

```
A = (32, 12, 46, 13, 75)
B = (55, 8,  68, 25, 41)
C = (43, 21, 64, 66, 64)
D = (56, 19, 17, 54, 89)
```

that I to be exhaustively compared (i.e. compute the euclidean distance between each pair) with each other:

```
A against B:  32 against 55, 12 against 8, 46 against 68, 13 against 25, 75 against 41
A against C:  32 against 43, 12 against 21 etc.
A against D
B against A
B against C
B against D
C against D
```

which has excluded the pairs A-A, B-B, C-C, D-D, B-A, C-A, C-B, D-A, D-B and D-C.

I see that for n elements, I have $ 2^n $ possible comparisons, from which $n$ are the comparisons with themselves.

If someone can point or provide some further analysis regarding the pairwise comparison I describe (e.g. how many commutative comparisons are there for $n$ elements) that would much appreciated.

Also, and perhaps more importantly, I am interested in finding out which algorithm would be the most efficient.

Comment: I think you need to define what you're trying to do more understandably than just saying "pairwise comparisons".

Comment: What are you looking for by comparing those sets? You need to sort something or you need to find some probable duplicated sets?

Comment: @HenningMakholm My bad for neglecting to describe that. I am looking at calculating the euclidean distance between each pair. (updated question's description)

Comment: @Majid As commented above, I have updated my question to include information required as your comment mentions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $n^2$ (not $2^n$) ordered pairs. Of these, $n$ are pairs of two identical elements. The remaining $n^2-n$ pairs each come in two different orders, of which you want only one, so you have $\frac{n^2-n}2$ different comparisons. This is $\binom n2$, the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) that counts the number of ways of choosing $2$ elements out of $n$.

Comment: That's great, thanks. I miss-typed the $n^2$, and the rest analysis was exactly what I wanted. But, how about an algorithm to perform these comparisons efficiently?

Comment: @user36227: There's not a whole lot you can do to do it more efficiently than in the naive approach. You can precalculate the sum of squares for each element; then instead of $\sum_i(a_i-b_i)^2$ you can calculate $\sum_ia_i^2+\sum_ib_i^2-2\sum_ia_ib_i$, which saves a couple of operations. In case your question was directed at the loops to enumerate the unordered pairs: In the outer loop, loop over all element indices, and in the inner loop, loop only over the smaller indices.